# removing a certain number from the output

Tags: python

I need help with this code

```
chapter_count_book_a = 20
verse_count_book_a = [100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]


def get_book_data(book,chapter_count, verse_count):
    if chapter_count != len(verse_count):
       print("ERROR!!!")
    answer = []
    for chapter in range(0,chapter_count):
        chp = book + "." + str(chapter+1)
        next_verse = verse_count[chapter]
        for verse in range(0,next_verse):
            answer.append(chp+"."+str(verse+1))
    return answer
book_a_data = get_book_data("66",chapter_count_book_a, verse_count_book_a)

print(book_a_data)
```

I have this code here, I try to remove it from every verse and chapter -7

How do I do that? I'm new to Python, so I'm going to need help from someone more advanced thanx

they need it to work as an answer but also to larger numbers and three numbers

```
input    ['66 .1.1 ', '66 .1.2', '66 .2.1 ', '66 .2.2', '66 .3.1 ', '66 .3.2','66.22.1']
```

and take -7 except for the first one to leave the original number

search for this input this output

```
['66 .-6.-6 ', '66 .-6.-5', '66 .-5.-6 ', '66 .-5.-5', '66 .-4.-6 ', '66 .-4.-5','66.15.-6']
```

Comment: I am little confused, what you doing here?

Comment: You have to explain a bit more because I cant understand what are you trying to do. What does your code do exactly and what you want your code to do?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but none of the code you've shown seems relevant to the question. It sounds like you want to *start* from what that code outputs, correct? Then all that matters is the `book_a_data`. (Also, what is this data used for? Because if it's anything other than just printing/displaying, a list of stings like this is probably not ideal.)

Comment: @BhusalC_Bipin I added a couple of lines maybe it's about understanding what I'm trying to do

Comment: @CrazyChucky I want to save all -7 except the first number if there are 3 numbers: D stormed in the calculation it can't be done until the data I have

Comment: @CrazyChucky the answer I have is correct but does not work correctly for all numbers book_a_data = ['66.22.1'] some numbers don't work ['66. -65. 1 '] give this number – – 
 example is bad number im search  '66.15.-6'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the more pythonic way but it works:

```py
result=[]
for chapter in book_a_data:
    for number in chapter.split("."):
        if number.isdigit():
            chapter = chapter.replace(number, f"{int(number)-7}", 1)
    result.append(chapter)

print(result)
```

Result:

```
['.1.1', '.1.2', '.2.1', '.2.2', '.3.1', '.3.2']
['.-6.-6', '.-6.-5', '.-5.-6', '.-5.-5', '.-4.-6', '.-4.-5']
```

---

If you want to change numbers avoiding the first one, you can do this(based on your answer)

```py
book_a_data = ['11.1.1', '66.22.1', '66.2.1', '66.2.2', '66.3.1', '66.3.2']
result=[]
kolik = -7
for chapter in book_a_data:
    new_chapter = ''
    for i, number in enumerate(chapter.split(".")):
        if number.isdigit() and i == 0:
            new_chapter = number
        if number.isdigit() and i != 0:
            number = f"{int(number) + kolik}"
            new_chapter = f"{new_chapter}.{number}"
    result.append(new_chapter)

print(result)
```

Result:

```
['11.-6.-6', '66.15.-6', '66.-5.-6', '66.-5.-5', '66.-4.-6', '66.-4.-5']
```

Comment: could i ask for a favor so the first issue doesn't change? only 2 and 3 thanx

Comment: `['66.1.1', '66.1.2', '66.2.1', '66.2.2', '66.3.1', '66.3.2']` if this is input

Comment: you would need to skip it `for i, number in enumerate(chapter.split(".")):
        if number.isdigit() and i != 0:`

Comment: book_a_data = ['66.22.1'] some numbers don't work ['66. -65. 1 '] give this number – –

Comment: @JohnBeats I did an update yesterday, you've got it in my answer above.

Comment: Input: `['11.1.1', '66.22.2', '66.2.1', '66.2.2', '66.3.1', '66.3.2']` Output: `['11.-6.-6', '66.15.-5', '66.-5.-6', '66.-5.-5', '66.-4.-6', '66.-4.-5']`

Comment: book_a_data = ['66.22.1']  look this number give bad result :D im solving

Comment: `for chapter in book_a_data:
    chapter_result = ''
    for i, number in enumerate(chapter.split(":")): 
        if i == 0:  
            chapter_result += number
        else:`

Comment: `chapter_result += str(int(number) + kolik)  
        
        chapter_result += ":"

    result.append(chapter_result[:-1])`

Comment: kolik = number this example -7